# Feature Recursive Patterns Is currently in Preview Version of Vs Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-warnings, c#-8.0

I am unable to use some piece of code introduced in [c# version 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8).

Consider this piece of code.

**Property patterns**

```
class Address
{

    public string State { get; set; }
}

public static decimal ComputeSalesTax(Address location, decimal salePrice) =>
location switch
{
    { State: "WA" } => salePrice * 0.06M,
    { State: "MN" } => salePrice * 0.75M,
    { State: "MI" } => salePrice * 0.05M,
    // other cases removed for brevity...
    _ => 0M
};
```

**Error:**

[image]

Please help me solve this , infact I am using latest version of vs code.

Comment: You need to tell VS Code that you want to use a newer (preview) language version of c#. Are you working on a project? If so you can put `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in the .csproj file. This might resolve the issue. You need to put it in the right place however.

Comment: Glad to help. I have posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231520/10883465). You should accept it so this question gets marked as solved/closed :)

Comment: i have marked it solved :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell VS Code that you want to use a newer (preview) language version of c#. Are you working on a project? If so you can put `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in the .csproj file. This might resolve the issue. You need to put it in the right place however.

Comment: ...aaand *the right place for that* is within `<PropertyGroup>` :)